# How to remove first two characters from a date string (MM/dd/yyyy) in array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, datetime, split

I have an array that stores date input from users but I want to remove or trim the first two characters (basically, I want to remove the month) from every date inputted in the array:

```
class MainClass
{ 
    {
    //Main Program....
    }

public static int GetInput (string[] date)
{
    int loop;

    (for int i=0 ; i < loop ; i++)
    dArray[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}  
}

class OtherClass
{ 
    //Required data properties, etc...

    public string TrimFirstTwoMonthChar(string dateInput)
    {
      char[] delimiter = {'/', '-', .... }

      string[] monthNumberRemoved = dateInput.Split(delimeter);

     // How would I code the rest of this function so that it removes the first 2 characters from "MM/dd/yyyy".  
     //Keep in mind I have also allowed users to input the date in formats like 
     //"M/dd/yyyy" (such as 3/07/2011 vs 03/07/2011) 
     //so sometimes I would only need to remove ONE NOT TWO of the month character //
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to reword you explanation in the comments.. you know if you think about this logically you can write something that if the value of the first 2 characters < 10 then you would format your date as `m/dd/yyyy` else `mm/dd/yyyy` of course using the substring function to check the length etc..

Comment: (for int i=0 ; i < loop ; i++) Does it even compiles???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With string, you can use a simple substring:

```
public static string TrimFirstTwoMonthChar(string dateInput)
{
    var indexOfFirstBar = dateInput.IndexOf('/');
    var start = indexOfFirstBar + 1;

    return dateInput.Substring(start, dateInput.Length - start);
}
```

But I suggest you to convert to DateTime and use the date format you want:

```
public static string TrimFirstTwoMonthChar(string dateInput)
{
    var date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateInput);
    return date.ToString("dd/yyyy"); // Use the format you want here
}
```

About [Convert.ToDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xhz1w05e.aspx) and [date formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public string TrimFirstTwoMonthChar(string dateInput)
{
  char[] delimiter = {'/', '-', .... }

  string[] monthNumberRemoved = dateInput.Split(delimeter);

  return monthNumberRemoved[1] + "/" + monthNumberRemoved[2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  It didn't occur to me to use that.  I was thinking more along the route of using Trim, Remove, or Substring but this works just as well.